# Check if a string contains a sequence of "udlr" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

If I have a string how can I check if the string contains any sequence of "rldu"? I am really new to ruby, sorry if this is a stupid question to ask.

r- right, l-left, d-down, u-up.

For example:

```
str = "udlv"      #should return false
str = "lrd"       #should return true
```

Comment: I'm confused. What do you mean by 'any sequence of "rldu"'? Your example seems to indicate you want to check that the string is composed of only the characters `r`, `l`, `d`, `u` (in any order) and nothing else, is that correct?

Comment: Why isn't your second example expected to return false? It does not have `"u"`.

Comment: SO members don't mind easy questions, if that's what you mean by a "stupid question".  What they do mind are sloppily-worded questions.  `...sequence of "ridu"` is meaningless.  Be clear, precise and complete!  Please edit your question rather than explain in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the string should entirely be composed of the given four characters in any order

```
str =~ /^[rldu]+$/
```

will return an integer or nil that you can use in a conditional. If you want a boolean, use the trick with `!!`:

```
!!str.match(/^[rldu]+$/)
```

Comment: Nik and @Ajedi32, I'm sorry to ruin your day, but the Ruby [style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) advises: "Avoid the use of !!".  You do want to be stylish, don't you?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Which one? The GitHub Ruby style guide for example doesn't mention that: https://github.com/styleguide/ruby. If you refer to https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide, the examples given don't even show the common use of `!!` in Ruby code, hence I'd happily ignore that advise.

Comment: mmm. it is so laconic that pleases my eye :) What is the alternative to !! trick ? The ternary operator is hardly better, in my opinion

Comment: @Michael, you fault me for not using a smiley? (Actually, your point is well-taken and useful.)

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to check whether the string contains **anything other than** `udlr`, then

```
!("udlv" =~ /[^udlr]/) # => false
!("lrd" =~ /[^udlr]/)  # => true
```

Answer (score 2):

This one does not use a regular expression:

```
p "udlv".count("^rlrd").zero?  #=> false
p "lrd".count("^rldu").zero?   #=> true
```

"^rldu" means "everything else than rldu"

Comment: Your code gives the opposite of the expected result. And it is tricky because you listed them in the opposite order as the OP. That can be fixed by using `zero?`.

Comment: @sawa thanks. That's what I had, but I got confused because I had the order of the strings reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by 'any sequence of "rldu"' you mean you want to verify that the string is composed of only the `r`, `l`, `d`, `u` (any number of times, in any order) and nothing else, a good old regular expression should work just fine:

```
str =~ /^[udlr]*$/
```

If you strictly need that to be a boolean value (true/false), then you can prefix it with two exclamation points (double not), like so:

```
!!(str =~ /^[udlr]*$/)
```

In most cases, you shouldn't need to do that because Ruby can interpret any value as either true or false anyway.

You can view the documentation for all of `String`'s core methods [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html). And [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) is a guide on regular expressions.